# Gradle: 'Normal' build vs. analysis build

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration

On my Jenkins (or some other CI server) I want to build the develop branch with full analysis, which includes:

- Checkstyle
- Emma (coverage for feature-, integration-, and unit-tests)
- FindBugs
- JSHint
- PMD (including CopyPasteDetection)

But at the same time I don't want all this stuff running, when I build locally.
A build on my development PC should only compile and run unit tests.

How does one solve this 'the gradle way'?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `analysis` task in your build.gradle that depends on all the analysis tasks you want to run on the CI server. Then in the "Tasks" section of the Jenkins configuration for your build, specify the `analysis` task instead of `build`.